# Binding to getInitialState?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Is it possible to bind to the `getInitialState()`?

```
BidLists = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(s) {
      return{
        filteredID: this.props.data,
        currentData: s
      }
    },
  renderBidContent: function(s) {
    return(
      <div>{s.support_title}</div>
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    var cards = this.props.data.slice(0,25).map( (s, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.getInitialState.bind(this,s)} // is this even possible?
        </div>
        );
     });
     var currentData = this.state.currentData;
     return(
       <div>{this.renderBidContent(currentData)}</div>
     );
  }
});
module.exports = BidLists;
```

Im getting:

> cannot read property 'support_title' of undefined

I seem to not binding `s` properly. Any help? I'm using React v0.14

**Reason behind this:**

In the `renderBidContent()` there will be another function loop. That loop will test against `s.id`. I can achieve this in the BidList's `render()` but the output is twice and I dont want that.

I'm trying to do something [like this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) but without a click method.

Comment: {this.getInitialState.bind(this,s)}  whar are you trying to do here

Comment: Trying to get the `s` variable inside the `renderBidContent()`

Comment: What is the use case? Can you discuss what you intend to accomplish in the BidLists component?

Comment: Hi @HaZardouS I have updated the post. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: My question was more towards knowing your business problem, like what the BidLists component is all about and what would its children component are supposed to do? The reason I am asking this is because from looking at the code I feel you are beginning to learn react (there are several problems in the code, e.g. render has two returns) and are trying to solve a problem in a non-react, probably jQuery like way. So your code will not help me truly understand what you are trying to solve. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Im new. `props` are job posts. The `renderBidContent()` will have a Firebase data query that matches the job post. Better?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, this isn't how bind works.

maybe you're looking for something like this

```
BidLists = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(s) {
      return{
        filteredID: this.props.data
      }
    },
  renderBidContent: function(s) {
    return(
      <div>{s.support_title}</div>
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.props.data.slice(0,25).map( (s, i) => {
      return <div>{this.renderBidContent(s)}</div>
    });
  }
});
```

#### How Bind Works

Bind doesn't actually bind the old function.  It creates a new function and binds context or variables to it. Bind works similar to currying.

consider this function

```
function multiply(x, y){
    return x * y
}
```

and now say I want to create a multiplyTwo function using the above function (we could also create our own but lets pretend multiply is an extremely complicated function).

Method 1, currying/closure.

```
function multiplyAny(num) {
    return function(y){
        return multiply(num, y);
    }
}

var multiplyTwo = multiplyAny(2);
multiplyTwo(5); //this should give you 10
```

Method 2 bind

```
var multiplyTwo = multiply.bind(null, 2);
multiplyTwo(5); //this should give you 10
```

bind is like a special kind of curry and creates a new function with some of the variables already set. The first variable is the context (a.k.a this keyword)

Comment: Who gave that down vote? Ok ill try that and report but i knew i was close to what i want in my code.

Comment: Im getting `Violation: BidLists.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: Where are you trying to render this? in another component? You can wrap it around with {BidLists.render()}

Comment: Yes. It renders as this: `<BidLists data={this.state.filteredID} />`